# C++ Length of a string in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

How would I be able to find the longest length in my string array?
I have several options to chose from, and the longest on is " How To Play", which is 12 characters long.
In a brief summary, how would I be able to find the longest part in my array and get the number? Here is my array:

```
string mainMenuText[] = {" Play game  ",
                         " Highscores ",
                         " Storyline  ", 
                         " How To Play", 
                         " Exit Game  "};
```

Comment: Could I make a variable when the number of options in my array, then do this in a for statement? const int numOpts = sizeof(mainMenuText) / sizeof(mainMenuText[numItems]);

Comment: Loop through the array, getting `mainMenuText[i].length()`. Choose the one with the highest length. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple code

```
int max=0;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    if(mainMenuText[i].size()>mainMenuText[max].size())
        max=i;
return mainMenuText[max];
```

Comment: If you want to print the text replace `return mainMenuText[max];` with `cout<<mainMenuText[max];`

Comment: I just want a number to return the longest length of the string!

Comment: Theirs no error, I figured it out but I want a number to display the strings length

Comment: `cout<<mainMenuText[max].size();`

Comment: You must have `i < 5` in your loop, or better, `i < sizeof(mainMenuText)/sizeof(*mainMenuText)`

Comment: @vsoftco Thanks for notifying me. I miscounted the number of elements. I modified my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can also use modern C++ standard library features from `#include <algorithm>`:

```
std::string mainMenuText[] = {" Play game  ", " Highscores ", " Storyline  ", 
                              " How To Play", " Exit Game  "};
auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(mainMenuText), std::end(mainMenuText),
    [](std::string& lhs, std::string& rhs){return lhs.size() < rhs.size();});
auto num = it->size(); // here is your max size
std::cout << "Longest: [" << *it << "] of size: " << num;
```

Comment: I just want a number to be returned instead! So if the longest length of a string in the array is twelve, return a number called int num = 12.

Comment: @ThatCoderBryan I hope you also realize that all strings in your array have the same length, due to space padding.

Answer (score 1):

To get the length of a `string`, you use the [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) member function.

To find the largest such `size()`, you just need to iterate through all the strings:

```
std::string::size_type max_size = 0;
const size_t NUM = sizeof(mainMenuText) / sizeof(*mainMenuText);
for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
    max_size = std::max(max_size, mainMenuText[i].size());
}
// max_size is now the maximum size
```

With C++11, we can shorten this a bit:

```
std::string::size_type max_size = 0;
for (const std::string& s : mainMenuText) {
    max_size = std::max(max_size, s.size());
}
```

Note, however, that all of your strings are the same length. I'm not sure if that was intentional or not. If you want to account for padding, I would add this function:

```
size_t trimmed_length(const std::string& s) {
    size_t start = s.find_first_not_of(' ');
    size_t end = s.find_last_not_of(' ');
    return (start == std::string::npos || end == std::string::npos)
            ? 0 : end - start + 1;
}
```

With:

```
size_t max_size = 0;
for (const std::string& s : mainMenuText) {
    max_size = std::max(max_size, trimmed_length(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is standard algorithm `std::max_element` that finds the first maximum element in the given sequence according to your criteria. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::string mainMenuText[] = 
    {
        " Play game  ", 
        " Highscores ", 
        " Storyline  ", 
        " How To Play", 
        " Exit Game  "
    };

    auto *it = std::max_element( std::begin( mainMenuText ), std::end( mainMenuText ),
                                 []( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
                                 {
                                     return s1.size() < s2.size();
                                 } );

    std::cout << "The longest string is \"" << *it << "\"" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "It has " << it->size() << " characters" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The longest string is " Play game  "
It has 12 characters
```

To get the index of the longest string you can use standard function `std::distance` declared in header `<iterator>`

For example

```
size_t pos = std::distance( std::begin( mainMenuText ), it );
```

or you can write simply

```
size_t pos = it - mainMenuText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Forgot to include the string library.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Put this on top of your code file.